# Prevent resize of the control that contains an ItemControl when there are no element in itemsSource in WPF without using fixed values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I have a ScrollViewer that contains an ItemsControl where the ItemsSource could be empty. I want to prevent that the ScrollViewer changes its height when ItemsSource is empty **without using a fixed value**. 
This is the code:

```
<ScrollViewer  
  Grid.Row="1" 
  Grid.Column="1"
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ExperimentPresets}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:ExperimentPresetInProcedureViewModel">
        <askTouch:ComposingProcedureItemView/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel 
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          Margin="0 8 0 24"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Which height it should have when it's empty? _Remember_ latest one?

Comment: The height of the ComposingProcedureItemView

Comment: It's inisde a `Grid` then you can use `IsSharedSizeScope` (if they're siblings). If container then you may set `ScrollViewer.HeightAlignment` to `Stretch` or...for more complex scenario directly use binding `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType...`

Comment: Using `ScrollViewer.VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` does not solve because the ScrollViewer is inside a Grid which resizes according to its content. The problem lies in the fact that the `ComposingProcedureItemView` UserControl has a fixed height but when `ItemsSource` is empty there is no placeholder to reserve the right space and the `ItemsControl.Height` becomes shorter